# obtener ultimo elemento por tipo

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa con herencia Empleado(Medico,Enfermera,Asistente). Quiero obtener el último elemento según el tipo. Tengo el siguiente método donde sí puedo listar por tipo pero no sé como hacer para obtener el último. listaEmpleados es un ArrayList

```
public static Empleado getUltimoPorTipo_2(String clase){
    System.out.println("\n\t\tLISTADO DE EMPLEADOS "+clase.toUpperCase());
    System.out.println("\n\t\t***********************");
           
     if(listaEmpleados.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No hay empleados.");
    }else{
        for(Empleado e:listaEmpleados){           
            if(e.getClass().toString().contains(clase)){
                //System.out.println(e.toString());//devuelve los empleados por tipo                
                return listaEmpleados.get(listaEmpleados.size()-1);
            }
        }
    } 
     return null;
}
```

Este código incorrecto lo que hace es devolverme el último de todos los tipos. A ver si me echáis una ayuda.
SALUDOS, GRACIAS.

Comment: una idea, podrias usar una lista adicional```indices``` donde almacenar los indices obtenidos al cumplir la condicional, ejemplo: si la clase fuese enfermera ..seria como ```indices.add(listaEmpleados.indexOf(e));``` y luego obtienes el ultimo objeto de dicha clase mediante ```listaEmpleados.get(indices.get(indices.size()-1));```

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo usar [`getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) para obtener el nombre de la clase en una variable de tipo String; Al usar `contains()` si tu clase fuese `Medico` con que tu coloques *Medi* o *Medic* incluso *M* como parámetro de clase.. esto sera valido por que Medico contiene *M* ..
Dicho esto podes guardar los objetos que pertenezcan a la subclase que quieres en un array o una lista y luego obtener el ultimo guardado.

```
static Empleado obtenerUltimoClase(List<Empleado>listaEmpleados,String clase){

   List<Empleado>empleadoFiltrados=new ArrayList<>();

   if(listaEmpleados.isEmpty()){
    return null;
   }else{
       for(Empleado p:listaEmpleados){
          if(p.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(clase)){
              empleadoFiltrados.add(p);
          }
       }
   }
     return empleadoFiltrados.get(empleadoFiltrados.size()-1);  
    }
```

variante usando java 8+

```
 static Empleado obtenerUltimoClase(List<Empleado>listaEmpleados,String clase){
    
      Empleado[]empleados=listaEmpleados.stream()
                          .filter(n->n.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(clase))
                          .toArray(Empleado[]::new);
    
      return listaEmpleados.isEmpty()?null:empleados[empleados.length-1];
    
        }
```

o

```
static Empleado obtenerUltimoClase(List<Empleado>listaEmpleados,String clase){

return  listaEmpleados
           .stream()
           .filter(n->n.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(clase))
           .reduce((first,second)->second).orElse(null) ;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres obtener la ultima instancia que cumple la condición una forma muy simple sin modificar mucho tu código original es usar una variable que sirva para mantener una referencia a la ultima instancia encontrada que cumple la condición:

```
public static Empleado getUltimoPorTipo(String clase){
    Empleado ultimo = null;
    for(Empleado e:listaEmpleados){           
        if(e.getClass().toString().contains(clase)){
            ultimo = e;
        }
    }
    return ultimo;
}
```

Pero esto es muy ineficiente porque te obliga a recorrer el array completo, es mas lógico recorrer el array de forma invertida, por ejemplo con JDK 21 puedes usar [`List#reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) que retorna una vista invertida:

```
public static Empleado getUltimoPorTipo(String clase){
    for(Empleado empleado:listaEmpleados.reversed()){           
        if(empleado.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(clase)){
            return empleado;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

o también:

```
public static Empleado getUltimoPorTipo(String clase){
    return listaEmpleados.reversed().stream()
        .filter(empleado -> clase.equals(empleado.getClass.getSimpleName()))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Dependiendo de la versión de Java que estés usando tienes varias opciones para recorrer el array de forma invertida sin necesidad de generar uno nuevo, desde iteradores al mas clásico `for`:

```
public static Empleado getUltimoPorTipo(String clase){
    
    for (int i = listaEmpleados.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (listaEmpleados.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals(clase)) {
            return listaEmpleados.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que iteres la lista y obtengas el último elemento del tipo Empleado, recuerda también retornar el objeto, ya que estás retornando `null`, lo cual es incorrecto.

Realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
public static Empleado getUltimoPorTipo(String clase) {
    System.out.println("\n\t\tLISTADO DE EMPLEADOS " + clase.toUpperCase());
    System.out.println("\n\t\t***********************");

    Empleado ultimoEmpleado = null; //*Para almacenar último elemento

    if (listaEmpleados.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No hay empleados.");
    } else {
        for (Empleado e : listaEmpleados) {
            if (e.getClass().toString().contains(clase)) {
                ultimoEmpleado = e; //*almacena último elemento
            }
        }
    }

    return ultimoEmpleado;
}
```